# sql not fetching the date range

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the below query

```
 SELECT * FROM music_history WHERE date1 BETWEEN 2017-06-24 AND 2017-06-01
```

when is run this query in `phpmyadmin` it says `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0011 sec )` even though i have date available from to that range in database.

Here is the database image

[image: database image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `BETWEEN` query, the two operands are ordered.  So, this should do what you want:

```
WHERE date1 BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-24'
```

I assume the lack of single quotes was just a typo.

I would encourage you to write the query using binary comparisons, in this fashion:

```
WHERE date1 >= '2017-06-01' AND date1 < '2017-06-25'
```

This works even when `date1` has a time component.

You might find [this blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) interesting.  Although it is about SQL Server, it really applies to any database:

Comment: thanks it works, but can we use these with `3 table joins`

Comment: @TomJerry . . . You can use a `WHERE` with however many joins you like.  They are separate SQL clauses.  If you have another question, though, you should ask *another* question, particularly because this one has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

First date should be less than second one. 
`BETWEEN` can be changed to

```
WHERE date1 > first AND date1 < second
```